# The word already converted to Unicode is also considered as a new user input and is converted again and again

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, unicode, pyautogui

The project that I am working on is a typing tool for local languages using Unicode characters.

I'm trying to develop a program that, whenever a word is typed, it is converted to the relevant Unicode word. (It identifies a word after pressing 'space.')

I found out that if *Ctrl+shift+u* is pressed and released, then the Unicode value is typed, and then a space, it is converted to the relevant Unicode character.

e.g.

```
1) Ctrl+shift+u
2) 0d96
3) space
    ->> ඖ
```

So, I developed this function with *pyautogui* which helps to press keys whenever needed.

if needed, the 'word' below passes the value like ***u0dbbu0ddd***  (not ***\u0dbb\u0ddd***)

```
import pyautogui

def type_unicode(word,lenth):
#word - converted unicode values
#length - length of the user typed word


#to erase user typed word
    for x in range(lenth+1):
        pyautogui.press('backspace')


    for x in range(0,len(word),5):
        # to  press ctrl+shift+u
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'u')

        #Unicode letters for each word
        pyautogui.typewrite(word[x+1:x+5])

    pyautogui.press('space')
```

The problem I am facing here is: when the user inputs his first word it converts to Unicode nicely, But the already converted word is instantly taken as another input, and the program tries to convert it Unicode again. This happens endlessly.

I tried with a flag but I could not resolve it.

Comment: Could you provide more information about pyautogui methods?

Comment: this document provides all the required details. https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html

Comment: I thought this method is better. but if there any other methods better than this,kindly request to suggest.

Comment: To better understand your problem it is probably necessary to know the entire code of your script and the environment you use the code for, not only the function. Where, when and how this function is called? What about using a special  key sequence like e.g. "[b][s][backspace][backspace]" emitted at the end of the conversion process (before [space]), which can be then identified as autogui and not user word input in order to skip using the function for the already converted word?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling pyautogui.press('space') in your program body, so even though the user is not typing the space, the program is seeing it as a space.

I think you are on the right track with using flags. However, since we don't have the code that handles a space, I can only take a stab at what can work.

I'm going to assume your space-handling function is called space_handler.

```
def space_handler(a, b, c):
```

Let's add a global variable to space_handler.

```
in_user_input = True

def space_handler(a, b, c)
    if not in_user_input:
        return False
    (....regular space handling)
```

Also, the places to change in_user_input are

```
    in_user_input = False
    for x in range(0,len(word),5):
        # to  press ctrl+shift+u
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'u')

        #Unicode letters for each word
        pyautogui.typewrite(word[x+1:x+5])

    pyautogui.press('space')
    in_user_input = True
```

It seems like you'd just need the in_user_input around pyautogui.press('space'), but if someone puts in unicode 0020 (a space,) that is potentially a mean edge case. There may be other edge cases. But I think this should mostly work.

Hope this helps, or better, you figured things out already.